# How to switch off the Procedure Seperator in VB.Net VS2008?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Apologies for the dumb question but it's driving me insane.
How to switch off the annoying (to me anyway) horizontal line that seperates procedures in Vb?

I've setup a new Dev machine for myself and for the life of me I can't figure out how to switch it off in VS2008.
My mind is obviously failing with age, I know I did it on the old machine!

The old machine is dead so I can't even import the settings from there.

Thanks,
BW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Basic > VB Specific.
Then uncheck "Show procedure line separators".

Comment: Thanks man. It's actually Windows-7, it show's little grey triangles in trees instead of plus signs. Therefore I didn't "see" that I could expand the "Basic" node to get "VB Specific". I'm not complaining, this new machine rally prods buttock :)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the color to white? (Or whatever you're using as the text background color)